# Return variable from stored procedure call as output value for variable

Tags: php, sql, db2

I'm currently running a stored procedure, which runs successfully, but after the call to a separate procedure I'd like to return the value of `V_R_ID` as an output value to be stored  in PHP

So in this example:

```
P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE V_H_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE V_R_ID VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
DECLARE V_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP ;

DECLARE C_NAME VARCHAR ( 45 ) DEFAULT 'EMAIL' ;

SELECT CAST ( NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA . H_ID_SEQUENCE AS VARCHAR ( 20 ) )
INTO V_R_ID
FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1 ;

CALL PROCEDURESCHEMA . INSERT_TYPE ( 
V_R_ID
, C_NAME
, IN_DATA
, NULL
, NULL ) ;

/*Here I'd like to declare V_R_ID as an output of RETURN_ID */

END P1
```

How can I properly do this so that after calling this procedure in PHP I can then set the RETURN_ID as a php variable `$returnID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider declaring an output parameter which from [DB2 docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_parameterlistsp.html):

> Output-only parameters, which return values from the stored procedure to the calling program.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc (OUT V_R_ID  VARCHAR (20))

   LANGUAGE SQL 

P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

   DECLARE V_H_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
   DECLARE V_R_ID VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
   DECLARE V_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP ;

   DECLARE C_NAME VARCHAR ( 45 ) DEFAULT 'EMAIL' ;

   SELECT CAST ( NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA . H_ID_SEQUENCE AS VARCHAR ( 20 ) )
   INTO V_R_ID
   FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1 ;

   CALL PROCEDURESCHEMA . INSERT_TYPE ( 
      V_R_ID
    , C_NAME
    , IN_DATA
    , NULL
    , NULL ) ;

END P1
```

Then in PHP, using [PDO prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#101993), call the procedure with `?` placeholder and bind it to a PHP variable:

```php
$dbh = new PDO("ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=****;" .
               "HOSTNAME=##.##.##.###;PORT=####;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", "user", "pass");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL myProc(?)"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20); 
$stmt->execute();

echo $return_id;
```

Similarly but slightly different, with PHP's [IBM DB2 module](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-bind-param.php) connection bind parameter to a string name of variable:

```
$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, "CALL myProc(?)");
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "return_id", DB2_PARAM_OUT);
db2_execute($stmt);

echo $return_id;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this makes sense and I will try it shortly

Comment: If I'm calling it with inputs in the pdo though, I'd have to bind those and call this as an output param right?

Comment: Yes, add `bindParam` lines for each needed corresponding input or output params matching `?` placeholders.

Comment: So, it wouldn't allow that as an output param because it wouldn't be unique so I made it OUT_V_R_ID. That should still work as expected right? I'm having trouble running it in an IDE and returning the ID